# object HTMLInputElement it shows this error

Tags: javascript, html

**html code**

```
<p id="value"></p>
Date to Travel <input type="date" id="date" name="date" />
```

**javascript code**

it looks clean code to me, don't know whats the problem in it

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("date").addEventListener("keyup", keyisup, false);
}

function keyisup() {
    document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = date;
}
```

Comment: Where is the `date` variable? Date is undefined right now..

Comment: so what should it would be there

Comment: like date is used by the id of input type id

Comment: @Mikey it is probably the HTML element, since browsers will put elements on the global object if they have an id. @Komaldeepchahal, if you were meaning to put your `date` element's value in the `value` element you probably meant to do `date.value` and not just `date`

Comment: @PatrickEvans Well I did not know browsers set the HTML elements in the globals scope, but I would never ever use it in this way if I want to grab a specific element.

Answer (score 1):

It shows `[object HTMLInputElement]` because you told it to do so.

```
document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = date;
```

In this code you are setting innerHTML to `date`, however you are not defining it anywhere. So what happens is that it takes global value `date` which is going to be a reference to `<input type="date" id="date" name="date" />`, because browser exposes HTML elements as global references if they have `id` attribute.

Possible solution could be:

```
function keyisup(e) {
    document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = e.target.value; // or this.value
}
```

Comment: still working thanks .. why this onkey function not working on chrome.. but its working on firefox –

Answer (score 0):

DId you try

```
function keyisup()
{
    document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = $('#date').val();
}
```

in case you are referring to input with id date

Comment: I don't see OP using jQuery or it being tagged

Comment: still working thanks .. why this onkey function not working on chrome.. but its working on firefox

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work

```
document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = document.getElementById("date").value;
```

this is answer which i found error by my own

thanks for all